# Given the space-time relations in Relativity, shouldn’t the Standard Model of particle physics require a time boson?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, spacetime, standard-model, bosons

Since the theory of relativity tells us that time is a dimension, and we are always moving forward along that dimension, doesn’t it follow that at the quantum level there must be some kind of boson pushing matter forward through time?  (In the same way that all motion through the 3 spatial dimensions requires force bosons).
Since acceleration of fermions (matter) to near-light speeds results in a relative slowing of passage through time, and if it was possible (I know it isn’t) to actually accelerate matter to the speed of light, that their relative speed through time would stop, doesn’t it follow that fermions move through the 4-dimensions of space-time at a constant speed of light, and that that some of that velocity through time gets shifted to velocity through the spatial dimensions at relativistic speeds?   The speed of light isn’t simply the maximum speed for particles: it’s the only speed.
The Standard Model of quantum physics tells us that the motion in the spatial dimensions requires bosons, so doesn’t the time dimension need them too?  If entropy is somehow that force, how does it push us forward along the time dimension … doesn’t it still need to be a boson particle?  We assume the existence of gravitons as a way of keeping quantum mechanics in alignment with all 4 of the classical forces.  The same way we exist in a Higgs field and a Gravity field, perhaps we also exist in a Time field.
As I’ve never seen this issue directly discussed, I assume that I must be somehow terribly way off base (perhaps ignorant of critical equations), but I would love to know why I’m wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this would follow at all. *"The Standard Model of quantum physics tells us that the motion in the spatial dimensions requires bosons, so doesn’t the time dimension need them too?"* What does this mean? What bosons do you think are associated with spatial motion?

Comment: Let's imagine a hypothetical universe where things aren't "moving forward along that dimension" but everything else is the same. I assume you would be happy with this universe having all the gauge bosons we know about but not a time boson. Well, the existence of the photon in this universe means electrons will exert forces on each other causing them to accelerate. Which means covering increasingly large distances for each fixed unit of time. But wait! I thought we started by assuming they didn't move through time! Looks like analogizing time to motion was always a bad idea.

Comment: Only acceleration needs force, not motion per se.

Comment: "all motion through the 3 spatial dimensions requires force bosons" -- This is not correct, for a few reasons. First, inertial motion does not require a force. Second, "motion" in the sense of a "trajectory" does not exist in quantum mechanics. The bosons mediate *local interactions* between fields that occupy the same point *in space and time*; but there is no such thing as "a space boson" or "a time boson."

Comment: Good question.  What if it is not time that requires a particle, but spacetime?  I'd suggest that you take a look at the theory loop quantum gravity, in which spacetime is particulate.  This becomes the background (or often called the stage) on which all other particles exist.   In my own speculative theory of gravity based on LQG, particulate space dilates with energy.  Light must travel between these particles, so the speed of light (and the rate of time) slows as they dilate.  If you think of LQG as the particle you are looking for, then time naturally flows in the way you envision.

Comment: Thank you all for your help; I see that I made multiple errors in my question, such as disregarding kinetic energy & only focusing on forces such as a magnetic field causing electrons to flow, then erroneously slapped the classical concept of trajectory onto quantum interactions. I think the LQG route is indeed the one I am looking for, and will be re-reading Dr Rovelli's work (apparently my first read didn't stick).  The two answers below gave me a lot of clarity: the arrow of time made me fail to treat the 4 dimensions equally, so the graviton seems to be the object of my quest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't at all clear, but I'm guessing from where you say *"The Standard Model of quantum physics tells us that the motion in the spatial dimensions requires bosons, so doesn’t the time dimension need them too?"*, what you mean is something like "Newton's laws and their relativistic generalisation tells us that *acceleration* in the spatial dimensions requires *forces* (which are mediated by bosons). Acceleration is a *3D spatial* concept, but spacetime is four dimensional - so is there a temporal part to it, and thus some temporal analogue of a 'force'?"

A 'force' is more accurately described as the rate of change of momentum (the mass times the velocity), and there is a 4D version of 3D linear momentum called the energy-momentum vector. The energy is the temporal component. The rate of change of the 4-momentum (which is called the [4-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force)) is made up of the ordinary 3-force and the *power*: the rate of change of energy.

If two particles interact (by exchanging bosons) then the change in momentum and energy of one particle is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the change in momentum and energy of the other particle. All the forces of nature exchange both momentum and energy, so we don't need any new forces or bosons.

Answer (score 5):

> In the same way that all motion through the 3 spatial dimensions requires force bosons).

This is a complete misunderstanding of the quantum field theoretical model, if you are talking of modeling the motion of a particle, an electron lets say, with creation and annihilation operators on the electron field.

The model is in  the [four dimension vector space  of special relativity,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) and the bosons, if you mean the photons, come into the picture when there are interactions between elementary particles. The interactions also obey the Lorentz transformation rules, which have all four dimensions.

There is no separation in the treatment of four vectors in the description of elementary particle interactions.